# How do I populate a tableView with comments simply?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am adding a comment section to my posts using the comments data for each post from Firebase. I have been reading tutorials from Firebase, answers to questions on StackOverflow, and Youtube tutorials, but I am still encountering issues. I am using the FirebaseUI Open Source Kit. Here is my JSON for Firebase:

```
 "posts" : {
    "-LhjroYuwrmhENr78QEQ" : {
      "comments" : {
        "-LhjrqSlNDl49q-f2IvJ" : "How is it going there?",
        "-Lhjry5Q02nk3UDuwl1V" : "I would like some help with Firebase Apps",
        "-LhjrzadaywBb2p2S63D" : "Do you think you can help me?"
      },
      "reports" : 0,
      "text" : "Ryan Here",
      "timestamp" : 1560950032828,
      "title" : "Hey",
      "userID" : "nyRBXSyyDhc1Qkypou0Iz0iMsyr1"
    },
    "comments" : {
      "-LhjrqSlNDl49q-f2IvK" : {
        "reports" : 0,
        "timestamp" : 1560950040707,
        "userID" : "nyRBXSyyDhc1Qkypou0Iz0iMsyr1"
      },
      "-Lhjry5Rr-DVxGdwgAhn" : {
        "reports" : 0,
        "timestamp" : 1560950071986,
        "userID" : "nyRBXSyyDhc1Qkypou0Iz0iMsyr1"
      },
      "-LhjrzadaywBb2p2S63E" : {
        "reports" : 0,
        "timestamp" : 1560950078142,
        "userID" : "nyRBXSyyDhc1Qkypou0Iz0iMsyr1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to populate my tableView, "commentsTable", with each comment as a unique cell with a label filled with the comment's text. I made a prototype cell with a label in my storyboard, then tried to post the text using the following code:

```
var post: Post?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(delegate!)
    ref.child("posts").child("comments").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {DataSnapshot in self.commentsTable})
    newCommentLabel.delegate = self
    let firebaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child("comments")

    let query = firebaseRef.queryOrderedByKey() /*or a more sophisticated query of your choice*/

    let dataSource = self.commentsTable.bind(to: query, populateCell: { (tableView: UITableView, indexPath: IndexPath, snapshot: DataSnapshot) -> UITableViewCell in

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary

        self.query?.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        })

        cell.textLabel?.text = firebaseRef.text

        return cell
    })
}
```

At the moment I have an error on the line "let dataSource = ..." that says "Value of type 'UITableView?' has no member 'bind'". I am not sure how to fix this error. My text seems the same as the Firebase docs.

I am also not sure exactly how to display the desired info in the tableView. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->   UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:200, height:50))
    cell.addSubview(label)
    return cell
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}

private func setMain() {
    guard let post = self.post else {
        return
    }
```

I am finding it difficult to satisfy all of the necessary conditions to present the comments. The tutorials and docs seem a bit vague or overwhelming with the amount of input necessary without sufficient explanation. I am hoping someone here may be able to help me simplify the process. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to first download all the comments. Store the comments in an array or dictionary. This is your datasource. You definitely dont want to be creating uitableview cells in ViewDidLoad.

Then when you call cellForRowAtIndexPath use your datasource (array/dict) of comments to populate the custom cell's fields that you made.

numberOfRowsInSection should be the size/count of your datasource.